# How to pass & return the values from lambda to ECS task

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have one lambda function which is calling ECS task. Now i want to pass the values of Lambda as input to ECS task and the ECS task's result should return to Lambda.

I have tried to run ECS task in lambda using **run_task()** Method. It returns only the information about the ECS task but not the result(Output) of ECS task and i am not able to pass the values as input to ECS tasks.

Any working example on how to properly pass and return data in ECS task?

Answer (score 4):

ECS Tasks are not API calls or functions which you can pass values to and expect a return values from. Run Task simply means to spin up a "container". If that container was up successfully depends on so many factors like:

- Is the referenced Docker image (in Task Definition) available
- Does the task have enough permissions
- Was the networking setup properly
- Primary container in the task is working fine and passing health checks
- and tons more!

So if you want your container to read a value dynamically. You can set that value from your lambda to SSM Parameter Store. And then your application running in ECS can read from Parameter Store.

```
Lambda -> save value in Parameter Store -> Run Task
ECS Task -> Read value from Parameter Store
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest to pass in 'dynamic' values into the task is to create an `overrides` dict/object and pass that into the `run_task` API call.

It is mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html) for example.