# Get data from AWS ECS run task back to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am running my container in ECS Fargate using Lambda. But I want output of my container back to my Lambda which seems not possible directly as per [How to pass & return the values from lambda to ECS task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966509/how-to-pass-return-the-values-from-lambda-to-ecs-task)

I also read its possible here https://nuvalence.io/insights/aws-step-function-integration-with-ecs-or-fargate-tasks-data-in-and-out/ but unable to work it out. My docker image returns few lines and want to capture in s3 and read back in Lambda again. My Lambda is as follows which is not working

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ecs')
    run_task = client.run_task(
        cluster='arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345:cluster/listmodels',
        enableExecuteCommand=True,
        group='family:listmodels',
        launchType='FARGATE',
        networkConfiguration={
            'awsvpcConfiguration': {
                'subnets': [
                    'subnet-12345',
                ],
                'securityGroups': [
                    'sg-12345',
                ],
                'assignPublicIp': 'ENABLED'
            }
        },
        overrides={
            'containerOverrides': [
                {
                    'name': 'listmodels',
                    'command': [
                        "ls",
                        "--target",
                        "dev"
                    ],
                },
            {'Name':'OUTPUT_LOCATION','value':'s3://sm1-retail/1.txt'}
            ],
            'executionRoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::509094867785:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole',
            'taskRoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::509094867785:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole',
        },
        propagateTags='TASK_DEFINITION',
        taskDefinition='listmodels-task'
    )
```

Getting below error and Iam sure this error is because I added
**{'Name':'OUTPUT_LOCATION','value':'s3://sm1-retail/1.txt'}**

```
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in overrides.containerOverrides[1]: \"Name\", must be one of: name, command, environment, environmentFiles, cpu, memory, memoryReservation, resourceRequirements\nUnknown parameter in overrides.containerOverrides[1]: \"value\", must be one of: name, command, environment, environmentFiles, cpu, memory, memoryReservation, resourceRequirements",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
```

I would like to know what is better approach to get output of my run_task? Since run_task does not return anything to calling function, I thought of writing logs to s3 and read it from there and that is also failing. Any help is appreciated.

**USECASE:** I need to run docker image and the ouput of docker image is few file names and based on that my program decides which all files got changed and take necessary action

Comment: Probably instead of passing the files changed as output why not create event notification for the files changed on S3 and trigger lambda to process them. With the above approach there would be coupling in your infra and also additional cost of step functions.

Comment: Thanks @vikram. This is not on s3 file system. We are using DBT and when any source changes, we get a notification and we need to know list of changes downstream to it. so we have dbt docker image and need to run some commands with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing `environment` [argument](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html). It should be:

```
        overrides={
            'containerOverrides': [
                {
                    'name': 'listmodels',
                    'command': [
                        "ls",
                        "--target",
                        "dev"
                    ],
                    'environment': [
                            {
                                'name': 'OUTPUT_LOCATION',
                                'value': 's3://sm1-retail/1.txt'
                            },
                        ]  
                },
            ],
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin for your help.  It did work but it did not create file 1.txt. Any idea what might have happened? ecsrole has full s3 access and in logs i dont see any error message. Am i missing anything else? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @sandeep007 For the new issue, you should make new question.